# navigation in itemtemplate with querystring wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, listbox, navigation, query-string, itemtemplate

I have a ListBox.ItemTemplate in ListBox inside wp7 app. What I want is to navigate to somepage when user clicks the title with titletext in querystring.

Currently it just navigates to somepage.

```
 <ListBox x:Name="lbname"  >
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid Background="White">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tbTitle" Grid.Row="0" Text="{Binding Title}" TextAlignment="Left"   FontFamily="Segoe WP" Foreground="#000000" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" >
                            <Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                                <Custom:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                                    <ic:NavigateToPageAction TargetPage="/Views/somePage.xaml"/>
                                </Custom:EventTrigger>
                            </Custom:Interaction.Triggers>
                        </TextBlock>
                        <TextBlock  x:Name="tbDesc" Grid.Row="1" Margin="11,0,0,0" Text="{Binding Desc}" TextAlignment="Left"  FontFamily="Segoe WP" Foreground="#000000" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}" />
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```

How to do that?

Comment: is there is any way to catch event in code behind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `HyperlinkButton` with `NavigateUri="{Binding NavigationURL}"`

Answer (score 0):

How about setting TargetPage="{Binding Address}"?

Comment: it throws error AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE, while binding